# OrdinalEncoder: pass levels to ordinal variable

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to encode variable "`Avaliação`" below with `OrdinalEncoder`, where the levels are `"Baixa" < "Média" < "Elevada"`

This is the data:

```
clientes = pd.DataFrame(
    data =
    [[1, "Baixa"], 
     [2, "Baixa"], 
     [3, "Média"], 
     [4, "Elevada"], 
     [5, "Baixa"], 
     [6, "Média"], 
     [7, "Elevada"]],
    columns = ["ID", "Avaliação"]
)
```

[image]

This is the code I'm trying:

```
ordinal_encoder = OrdinalEncoder( categories= [("Baixa", 0), ("Média", 1), ("Elevada", 2)])
clientes_ordinal = ordinal_encoder.fit_transform(clientes[["Avaliação"]])

clientes_ordinal
```

So I'm passing the levels `0, 1, 2` to represent the order of the variable to the OrdinalEncoder object.

This is returning:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-112-98b05d548aed> in <module>()
      1 
      2 ordinal_encoder = OrdinalEncoder( categories= [("Baixa", 0), ("Média", 1), ("Elevada", 2)])
----> 3 clientes_ordinal = ordinal_encoder.fit_transform(clientes[["Avaliação"]])
      4 
      5 clientes_ordinal

2 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py in _fit(self, X, handle_unknown)
     76         if self.categories != 'auto':
     77             if len(self.categories) != n_features:
---> 78                 raise ValueError("Shape mismatch: if categories is an array,"
     79                                  " it has to be of shape (n_features,).")
     80 

ValueError: Shape mismatch: if categories is an array, it has to be of shape (n_features,).
```

Although I can't figure out where the mismatch is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to (and cannot) specify the values to be taken, just the order.

```py
ordinal_encoder = OrdinalEncoder(categories=
    [["Baixa", "Média", "Elevada"]]
)
```

should work.  (The outermost list is to specify the columns, of which you have just one.  That's the source of your `ValueError`, but just adding an outer list to your code would produce an error about unhashable arrays.)